# Write two different size array data in a CSV file

Tags: arrays, numpy, csv, multidimensional-array, netcdf

I'm reading two different dimensional array variable (Time and a 3 layer variable) from **NetCDF** file. Details given below:

```
>>>array(['2018-07-15 00:00:05', '2018-07-15 00:00:20',
       '2018-07-15 00:00:35', ..., '2018-07-17 23:59:29',
       '2018-07-17 23:59:44', '2018-07-17 23:59:58'], dtype='<U19')

>>>masked_array(
  data=[[ 270,  554, 2068],
        [ 270,  554, 2068],
        [ 270,  554, 2068],
        ...,
        [ 704, 1034, 1349],
        [ 704, 1019, 1349],
        [ 704, 1019, 1349]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=999999,
  dtype=int16)
```

I would like to write above two variables in a **.csv** in 4 columns with header: 'Time','Layer1','Layer2','Layer3'. Like given below,

```
Date                    Layer1  Layer2  Layer3
2018-07-17 00:00:00     210.0   1139.0  NaN
2018-07-17 00:00:00     210.0   1139.0  NaN
2018-07-17 00:00:00     210.0   1139.0  NaN
2018-07-17 00:00:00     210.0   1139.0  NaN
2018-07-17 00:01:00     210.0   1139.0  NaN
2018-07-17 00:01:00     210.0   1139.0  NaN
2018-07-17 00:01:00     210.0   1139.0  NaN
2018-07-17 00:01:00     210.0   1154.0  NaN
2018-07-17 00:02:00     210.0   1154.0  NaN
2018-07-17 00:02:00     210.0   1154.0  NaN
2018-07-17 00:02:00     210.0   1019.0  1154.0
2018-07-17 00:02:00     210.0   1019.0  1154.0
```

Comment: I would make a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) DataFrame and is it’s `to_csv` method. It also looks like you’re working with geospatial data so you might want to check out https://geopandas.org/ too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trick here is getting the formatting right by using [left justification](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
import numpy as np
times = np.array(['2018-07-15 00:00:05', '2018-07-15 00:00:20',
       '2018-07-15 00:00:35', '2018-07-17 23:59:29',
       '2018-07-17 23:59:44', '2018-07-17 23:59:58'], dtype='<U19')

data = np.ma.array(
  data=[[ 270,  554, 2068],
        [ 270,  554, 2068],
        [ 270,  554, 2068],
        [ 704, 1034, 1349],
        [ 704, 1019, 1349],
        [ 704, 1019, 1349]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=999999,
  dtype=np.int16)

with open('data.csv', 'wt') as outfile:
    outfile.write('{:<23s} {:<7s} {:<7s} {:<7s}\n'.format(
        'Date', 'Layer1', 'Layer2', 'Layer3'))
    for t, row in zip(times, data):
        outfile.write('{:<23s} {:<7.1f} {:<7.1f} {:<7.1f}\n'.format(t, *row))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This code is running successfully, but all data is witting in single column of csv file. Could you suggest me for same?

Comment: Well I followed what you put in your question, which didn't have any commas in between the columns of data (CSV == "comma separated values"). Try adding some commas to the write statements.

Comment: Again Thank you so much. Now it is separating data column wise.